# Change text label where inside there are an input checkbox element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label, innerhtml

I have this part of html on my form:

```
<label class="ideal-radiocheck-label" onclick="">
    <input id="pagamento_8" class="_input " type="checkbox" onclick="half(this,value);" checked="" value="980" name="pagamento[]" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="ideal-check checked"></span>
    988 (980-980 €)
</label>
```

It is a checkbox input button that call the function half() to make something like call the next function:

```
function setClickedLabel(clicked,new_value){
    label_e=$(clicked).parent();
    label_t=$(label_e).text();
    labels_t=label_t.split('-');
    $(label_e).html(labels_t[0]+'-'+new_value+' €)');          <-- 1
    //$(label_e).text(labels_t[0]+'-'+new_value+' €)');        <-- 2
    //$(label_e).innerHTML = labels_t[0]+'-'+new_value+' €)';  <-- 3
}
```

Here i would change a part of the label "988 (980-980 €)" (the last 980) and the "clicked" variable is the input object that you can see inside the label element.

Using one of the three methods reported i got 2 effect. Whit 1,2 it changes the label but it removes the input element. Whit 3 it doesn't make nothing.

What function i can use? How i must fix the code to get what i need? 
Html can't be changed.

Maybe another alternative without [appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828273/hide-text-but-not-input-inside-a-label-jquery).

tnx,
j.

Comment: What is `half()` ? Why you are calling it? i think you just misplaced it instead `setClickedLabel()`

Comment: `value` in that scope is probably undefined, but you're passing `this`, so just get `clicked.value` inside the function? Getting the textnode (< search for this) is somewhat more involved and requires some filtering, but should be straight forward.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xBtWD/

Comment: half() is a big function where among other things i call setClickedLabel().

Comment: no value got the right scope because it's a constant and it's not refer to clicked.value. The problem is not on "undefined" value or the scope but i think on .text() .html() and innerHTML work.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the script on [jsfindle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBtWD) left on the comment from [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) i have wrote that solution. Maybe can be other better solutions.

```
function setClickedLabel(clicked,new_value,old_value){
    label = $(clicked).parent().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length;
    }).get(0);

    label.nodeValue = label.nodeValue.replace(new RegExp("-"+old_value), "-"+new_value);
}
```